# Is there a shorthand for inserting .NET Blazor components with multiple cascading values?

Tags: .net, components, blazor, cascading

I am working on a .NET Blazor project and need to pass multiple cascading values to a generic subform. The following code, which applies multiple [CascadingValue] attributes, works fine for passing a few values but becomes a little cumbersome when passing many more than that. Is there a shorthand for passing multiple values via a single [CascadingValue] attribute? If not, is there a more compact way to pass a larger number of values? (BTW - I do understand that there are alternatives to giving each attribute a name).

```
<CascadingValue Value="@Value1" Name = "Name1" > 
     <CascadingValue Value="@Value2" Name = "Name2" > 
            <CascadingValue Value="@Value3" Name = "Name3" > 
                <FooComponent />
             </CascadingValue>
     </CascadingValue>
</CascadingValue>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an object with all values you want to pass and use it like this

```
<CascadingValue Value="@AnyObject" IsFixed="true">
</CascadingValue>
```

Comment: I like that solution, but how would I get the cascaded object in the child component as the [CascadingParameter] attribute cannot be applied to an object?

Comment: [CascadingParameter]
protected AnyObject Context { get; set; }

Comment: I tried this but could not get it to work.  However, a slightly modified version (below) does work.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Surinder's answer, here is an expanded example with the child code that worked to get the object.

PARENT

```
<CascadingValue Value="@anyObject" IsFixed="True" Name="AnyName">
    <ComponentName />
</CascadingValue>

@code {        
      private ObjectType anyObject = new();
  }
```

CHILD

```
@code {
   [CascadingParameter(Name = "AnyName")]
   private ObjectType anyObject { get; set; }
}
```